# Altering button title it becomes inactive

Tags: 7, theming, forms

The override function I use in my bootstrap sub-theme template.php:

```
function subtheme_form_titles_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Activate'),   
  );
}
```

I use this, so I could replace a default 'Save' title of the button to 'Activate'. Funny thing is that it does replace the button title, but then when using the form and trying to save it by pressing 'Activate', nothing happens, the page just refresh, but content doesn't get created.

Also for some reason it change button class from btn-primary to btn-default. This shouldn't be happening. I just want to replace button text and keep default btn-primary class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're removing the submit handler from the element (see [`node_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_form/7), towards the end). You should just change what you need to instead of replacing the whole thing:

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('Activate');
```

> Also for some reason it change button class from btn-primary to btn-default. This shouldn't be happening.

That's not true, it *should* be happening. The `btn-primary` class is applied for submits with one of the following values:

- 'Save'
- 'Confirm'
- 'Submit'
- 'Search'

Comment: Correct. '$form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'btn-primary';' solved the problem.

Comment: Sorry got one of those wrong - you can either edit `_bootstrap_colorize_button` or add it to the form element's attribute array manually (probably easier to the second to be honest)

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is this line:

```
$form['actions']['submit'] = array(
```

It replaces original button with your own brand new array. Nothing in it, except what you put there. Original node form have submit function connected directly to a button, but you destroyed that with this line.

Instead of deleting original array and creating new one, consider simply altering values you need altered, like:

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('Activate');
```

Comment: Works, but it still change the class.

Comment: @OptimusPrime Clive's answer tells you why. But you can add class manually using `#attributes`. See Form API reference for details.